# why by Contact.findByIdAndDelete(req.query.id) is not deleting contact from my mongoDb Database(when not using await keyword before Contact word)?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

```
app.post('/create',async(req,res)=>{
  // console.log("**********123",req);
  // console.log("*************************************************************************************");
  // console.log("**********",req.body);

  Contact.create(req.body);

  // let list=await Contact. Find({});

  return res.redirect('back');

})
```

this post request successful add contact in database.(without await keyword before `Contact.create(req.body))`. But when,

```
app.get('/delete',async(req,res)=>{
  // console.log("**********123",req);
  //   console.log("*************************************************************************************");
  // console.log("**********",req.query.id);
  // Contact.create(req.body);

  Contact.findByIdAndDelete(req.query.id);

  return res.redirect('back');

})
```

this get request not delete contact from database because i have not add await before Contact.findByIdAndDelete(req.query.id), why this not deleting contact from database?
As first post request is adding contact in database successfully, why both is asynchronies functionality function. I am using express Js and ODM is Mongoose.

Please explain me? why it is happing?

Answer (score 0):

`findByIdAndDelete` does not actually return a `Promise` as you might have expected. Instead, it's an object with [a method named `then`](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/67b42244d7da2ec8597e21ea5699915dc3a12a06/types/query.d.ts#L702-L706) ([MSDN calls these 'Thenables'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#thenables)) which gets called when the object is `await`ed.

Comment: thank you so much for help. i gotted this point